# Select input not showing options

Tags: html

I am creating a web form. Here you have the code for two of the inputs:

```html
<div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-3  control-label">Nivel de usuario</label>
                          <div class="col-sm-9">
                              <select class="form-control" id="txtnivel_usuario" >
                              
                                  <option value="1" selected="selected" selected=true> Usuario </option>
                                  <option value="3"> Administrador </option>
                                  <option value="5"> Superadministrador </option>
                            
                              
                              </select>
                          </div>
                        </div>
    
    
    
                        
                         <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-3  control-label">Verificado</label>
                          <div class="col-sm-9">
                              <select class="form-control" id="txtverified" >
                              
                                  <option value="1" selected="selected" selected=true> Si </option>
                                  <option value="0"> No </option>
                            
                              
                              </select>
                          </div>
                        </div>
```

At the first select input, the browser is not showing the default selected value. At the second select input, the browser is showing the default selected value, in this case: 'Si'.

I am not able to find the reason for this behaviour.
I have checked it several times, and detected that changing the id value for the first select input makes it work, but I don´t understand why. 
Thank you.

EDITED:

[image]

EDIT #2

```
 <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-3  control-label">Nivel de usuario</label>
                          <div class="col-sm-9">
                              <select class="form-control" id="txtnivel_usuario" >

                                  <option value="1" selected="selected" > Usuario </option>
                                  <option value="3"> Administrador </option>
                                  <option value="5"> Superadministrador </option>


                              </select>
                          </div>
                        </div>




                         <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-3  control-label">Verificado</label>
                          <div class="col-sm-9">
                              <select class="form-control" id="txtverified" >

                                  <option value="1" selected="selected" > Si </option>
                                  <option value="0"> No </option>


                              </select>
                          </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Works for me. https://jsfiddle.net/762ak0e9/ Keep in mind that browsers may track how you manually set the form and recover that rather than using the HTML encoded settings.

Comment: only selected=selected is sufficient, no need to add selected=true

Comment: Which browser? Firefox for instance would show the one selected the last time the form was submitted. Changing the ID and it working is a clue. Try clearing the cache to see if that makes it work.

Comment: @mvasco Try CTRL+F5 to refresh without caching. Otherwise, I'd have to say that the code you provided is not the same as the code used to generate the screenshot.

Comment: @SloanThrasher; I am using Chrome

Comment: @Ouroborus, same result with CTRL+F5

Comment: @mvasco Then the code you've provided is not the same as the code used to generate the screenshot.

Comment: @Ouroborus; it is the same

Comment: @mvasco Provide a working example (jsfiddle.net or codepen.io) and steps to reproduce the issue.

Comment: `selected=true` is just plain wrong and probably the cause if your problem.

Comment: @NisseEngström, may be, but take into account that both select inputs have the same selected=true. I have removed both entries and the same result.

Comment: @Ouroborus, I have included a second edit, and put there the view source code from CHROME browser, including the proposal from NisseEngstrom

Comment: If I change id='txtnivel_usuario´ for id=´txtn' it works... any explanation?